# vCard Microformat on a web page

Tags: outlook, rdf, microformats, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to use the [vCard Microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) standard to provide a VCF export option on a web page, but when I try to export to Outlook 2003, it doesn't show the phone numbers at all. Here's the vCard code in the page; is this normal for Outlook to not pull in the phone numbers?

```
<div id="" class="vcard" style="float:left; display:inline-block;">
 <a class="url fn n" style="color: #EEFDFD; text-decoration:none" href="http://www.unctv.org">
 <span class="given-name"></span>
  <span class="additional-name"></span>
  <span class="family-name"></span>
 </a>
 <div class="org">UNC-TV</div>
 <div class="adr">
  <div class="street-address" style="display:inline">10 T.W. Alexander Drive, P.O. Box 14900</div>,
  <span class="locality">Research Triangle Park</span>, 
  <span class="region">N.C.</span> 
  <span class="postal-code">27709-4900</span>
  <span class="country-name"></span>
 </div>
 <span class="tel">
  (919) 555-7000
 </span>, 
 <span class="tel">
  <span class="type">Fax</span> 
    <span class="value">(919) 555-7201</span>
 </span>,
 <a class="email" id="email" style="color: #EEFDFD; text-decoration:none" title="Click to email UNC-TV" href="mailto:some_email@somedomain.com">some_email@somedomain.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the issue is in the export tool I'm using: Tails Export for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2240/). It needs to specify the phone as "tel;fax:(919) 555-5555", but instead, it lists it as "tel:Fax (919) 555-5555" in the .vcf file. Therefore, Outlook is unable to parse it.

Comment: Are there any other Firefox extensions that can handle this correctly?

Comment: Have you tried Operator?

Comment: Thanks, cygri. That did the trick :)
It was able to pull both phone numbers, the address, and the email correctly into the .vcf file. Excellent! You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Operator plugin, as suggested by cygri, does the job. I'm using both the Tails Export and Operator to show the power of microformats to folks.